# Crystal Report Missing Current values error while executing via C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I designed a crystal report and tested it by previewing and printing, where the parameter value is prompted.
On using the same report in c# on button click event, Parameterfieldcurrent value exception occurs, saying missing parameter values.
I used the following code,

```
      try
        {


            ReportDocument r2 = new ReportDocument();
            r2.Load(@"C:\\REPORTS\\RptBill.rpt");
            r2.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "localhost", "database");
            r2.Refresh();
            r2.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "printername";
            int idx = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
            ParameterField pfItemYr = new ParameterField();
            pfItemYr.ParameterFieldName = "bill_no"; 
            ParameterDiscreteValue dcItemYr = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            dcItemYr.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();


            pfItemYr.CurrentValues.Add(dcItemYr);

            paramFields.Add(pfItemYr);
            r2.PrintToPrinter(1, false,0,0);

        }
        catch(Exception em)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error is: " + em);
        }
```

EDIT: As @Roger Suggested i used set parameter value of report document and it worked. Code is as below,

```
            int idx = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            string parv = dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
            ReportDocument r2 = new ReportDocument();
            r2.Load(@"C:\\REPORTS\\RptBills.rpt");
            r2.SetDatabaseLogon("User", "Password", "localhost", "database");
            r2.Refresh();
            r2.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printera4name;
            r2.SetParameterValue("bill_no",parv);
            r2.PrintToPrinter(1, false,0,0);
```

Comment: Is `pfItemYr.CurrentValues` null?

Comment: I notice you’re creating an instance of ParameterFields but then never doing anything with it, so I suspect that’s going to be your problem.

ReportDocument does contain a ParameterFields property, perhaps you need to add your parameter fields to that instance instead of the instance you have created. I also notice that ReportDocument has a SetParameterValue() method which you may be able to make use of.